# PHP Mongo credentials rise 'No candidate servers found' error

Tags: php, mongodb

I changed my connection string from

```
mongodb://server1,server2/database
```

to

```
mongodb://user:pass@server1,server2/database
```

this results in the error 'no candidate servers found'.

It does not make sense to me because I did not change the hosts, I just added authentication. This error normally appears when none of the hosts is online reachable, which is not the case here.

How to solve this?

I also tried with `?replicaSet=xxxx&authSource=admin` appended and I tried with password urlencoded.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to define `authSource` parameter.

Example:

```
mongodb://user:pass@server1,server2/database?authSource=admin
```

P.S. the `replicaSet` parameter also should be defined.

Comment: Still the same error, I also added the replica set parameter :-(

Comment: I think the problem is Shanty, a library which hasnt been updated for 4 years.... it doesn't handle multiple hosts properly >.<